# I need to verify that the Huawei Health app is installed on IOS

Tags: swift, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

does anyone know how I can verify that the huawei health application is installed on an IOS device using swift? I haven't found a way.

Comment: Easiest way is to probably just ask the user - "hi do you have the Huawei Health app installed?"

Answer (score 1):

iOS has very strong security protections - every app is sandboxed and so you have no way of automatically checking whether a user has the app without some kind of permission on their part.

Your best bet would be to use a universal link to link them to the Huawei health app, but I don't think you will have a way of verifying the link works.